# How to get Specific values from printed value on Python and sort from high to small

Tags: python

I am trying to use binance api for my project I would like to list top gainers and sort them from high to small I tried couple of things but those  did not work.

I would like to print  only **"symbol"** and **"priceChangePercent"**.
Is there any way to get these two values?

This is my output:

```
[
   {
      "symbol":"FIDABUSD",
      "priceChange":"0.41800000",
      "priceChangePercent":"6.375",
      "weightedAvgPrice":"6.95111809",
      "prevClosePrice":"6.54400000",
      "lastPrice":"6.97500000",
      "lastQty":"28.30000000",
      "bidPrice":"6.97400000",
      "bidQty":"74.80000000",
      "askPrice":"6.97900000",
      "askQty":"3.30000000",
      "openPrice":"6.55700000",
      "highPrice":"7.20000000",
      "lowPrice":"6.47700000",
      "volume":"354812.40000000",
      "quoteVolume":"2466342.89060000",
      "openTime":1633166019175,
      "closeTime":1633252419175,
      "firstId":78716,
      "lastId":88805,
      "count":10090
   },

   {
      "symbol":"FIDABNB",
      "priceChange":"0.00093000",
      "priceChangePercent":"6.008",
      "weightedAvgPrice":"0.01614960",
      "prevClosePrice":"0.01546000",
      "lastPrice":"0.01641000",
      "lastQty":"109.10000000",
      "bidPrice":"0.01643000",
      "bidQty":"97.50000000",
      "askPrice":"0.01649000",
      "askQty":"140.60000000",
      "openPrice":"0.01548000",
      "highPrice":"0.01663000",
      "lowPrice":"0.01533000",
      "volume":"75225.50000000",
      "quoteVolume":"1214.86161500",
      "openTime":1633166016671,
      "closeTime":1633252416671,
      "firstId":8400,
      "lastId":9840,
      "count":1441
   },
]
```

Here's what I tried:

```
class BinanceConnection:
def __init__(self, file):
    self.connect(file)

""" Creates Binance client """

def connect(self, file):
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(file)]
    key = lines[0]
    secret = lines[1]
    self.client = Client(key, secret)


if __name__ == '__main__':

connection = BinanceConnection(filename)
prices = connection.client.get_ticker()

print(prices)
```

Comment: Yes, sort using a [custom key](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions). If I understand what you're asking for correctly.

Comment: *i tried couple things but those are did not work i* - please share it so we can have a look.

Comment: i updated the code check it please

Comment: @MehmetReşatDemir - we cant see any code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see below - a 1 liner

```
data = [
   {
      "symbol":"FIDABUSD",
      "priceChange":"0.41800000",
      "priceChangePercent":"6.375",
      "weightedAvgPrice":"6.95111809",
      "prevClosePrice":"6.54400000",
      "lastPrice":"6.97500000",
      "lastQty":"28.30000000",
      "bidPrice":"6.97400000",
      "bidQty":"74.80000000",
      "askPrice":"6.97900000",
      "askQty":"3.30000000",
      "openPrice":"6.55700000",
      "highPrice":"7.20000000",
      "lowPrice":"6.47700000",
      "volume":"354812.40000000",
      "quoteVolume":"2466342.89060000",
      "openTime":1633166019175,
      "closeTime":1633252419175,
      "firstId":78716,
      "lastId":88805,
      "count":10090
   },

   {
      "symbol":"FIDABNB",
      "priceChange":"0.00093000",
      "priceChangePercent":"6.008",
      "weightedAvgPrice":"0.01614960",
      "prevClosePrice":"0.01546000",
      "lastPrice":"0.01641000",
      "lastQty":"109.10000000",
      "bidPrice":"0.01643000",
      "bidQty":"97.50000000",
      "askPrice":"0.01649000",
      "askQty":"140.60000000",
      "openPrice":"0.01548000",
      "highPrice":"0.01663000",
      "lowPrice":"0.01533000",
      "volume":"75225.50000000",
      "quoteVolume":"1214.86161500",
      "openTime":1633166016671,
      "closeTime":1633252416671,
      "firstId":8400,
      "lastId":9840,
      "count":1441
   }
]

data = sorted([{'symbol':x['symbol'],'priceChangePercent':x['priceChangePercent']} for x in data],key = lambda k: float(k['priceChangePercent']), reverse=True)
print(data)
```

output

```
[{'symbol': 'FIDABUSD', 'priceChangePercent': '6.375'}, {'symbol': 'FIDABNB', 'priceChangePercent': '6.008'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
data = *your data*
newlist = list()
for item in data: 
    newlist.append({key:item[key] for key in ['symbol', 'priceChange']})

print(sorted(newlist, key=lambda k: k['priceChange'], reverse=True) )
```